# .gz + .zip разархивировать. android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, zip

Есть url, по которому приходит архив *.gz. Когда разархивирую его, получаю архив *.zip.
Мне нужно получить этот архив .gz, не сохраняя его на устройстве, затем вытащить .zip, разархивировать его и сохранить в папку на устройстве.

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = null;

try {
    is = url.openStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
    int n;

    while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
        baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
    }

    GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(gzipOutputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Кажется это бред и я что-то не понимаю в работе с i/o потоками. Пожалуйста объясните)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил сам ответить на вопрос. Этот код помогает разархивировать tar.gz, получить то, что внутри и раскидать по папкам. Надеюсь кому-то это поможет)**

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(downloadFile("http://urlFile"));
final List<File> untaredFiles = new LinkedList<>();
TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(in));
TarArchiveEntry entry;
final File path = new File(strings[0] + "/Folder");
if (!path.exists()){
   path.mkdirs();
}
while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry)tarInput.getNextEntry()) != null) {
      final File outputFile = new File(path, entry.getName());
      if(entry.isFile()) {
         if(!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
             outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
         }
         byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)entry.getSize()];
         tarInput.read(bytes);
         FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
         stream.write(bytes);
         stream.close();
      }
      if(entry.isDirectory()) {
         continue;
      }
      untaredFiles.add(outputFile);
}
```

**Метод downloadFile:**

```
 public static byte[] downloadFile(String urlString) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    return EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
}
```

**Код сыроват, но работает.**

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что вы используете *OutputStream там, где нужно использовать *Inputstream.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/data.json.gz");
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

И далее навернуть ZipInputStream. Тут еще следует учесть, что в zip архив может содержать несколько сущностей/файлов.

Comment: Not in GZIP format.

Comment: Хотя я уверен, что придёт именно tar.gz
ZipInputStream проходит, но тогда ZipEntry пустой(